# Embed a short compact version of a Gist in HTML

Tags: html, github, gist

Ok, so here for example let's say I want to embed a long gist such as doing:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/benanne/3274371.js"></script>
```

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/benanne/3274371

However, the embedded Gist is too long in my webpage and I would like it to show as just a few lines that could be either scrolled or unwrapped by clicking, etc.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: Can you link to the page or put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Added example link to a Gist. Also, the HTML webpage I want to include a Gist into will be a new article on this section of a website: https://vooban.com/en/tips-articles-geek-stuff/ . I would expect a solution to work on any web page rather than just this one. If I can't use a Gist for that I might end up with a Git repo or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the gist call in a container, style that and job done.

**Edit** just noticed the requirement to show/hide all, jQuery makes this trivial, you haven't mentioned jQuery or javascript in your question so I've come up with a hacky CSS/html option using target

```css
.gistcontainer {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.gistcontainer:target .show {display:none;}
.gistcontainer:target {max-height:none;}
```

```html
<div class="gistcontainer" id="gist1">
  <a href="#gist1" class="show">More...</a>
  <script src="https://gist.github.com/benanne/3274371.js"></script>
</div>
```

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950812/gist-how-to-set-the-height-and-width-of-an-embedded-gist) may also be of interest, particularly the fact the CSS classes used by gist seem to have changed over time, so a "wrapped" solution may be more future proof.