# Change font in Github Flavored markdown for Table

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am creating a Wiki page in [`github.com`](http://github.com). I am trying to use table in the `Markdown` edit mode. I created table by embedding html expecting to add inline-css later but found that inline-css also not working.

I tried following:

```
<style>
  .markdown-body table td {
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
</style>
```

[Link for my wiki page.](http://goo.gl/A7ljvI)

Have anyone tried it before or achieved similar things or any help?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have managed to make the font size small in table by using `<sub>...</sub>` tag.

Achieved this by Wrapping each line of text (inside `td`) under `<sub>...</sub>`.

[UPDATED WIKI LINK](http://goo.gl/douSKv)

Comment: +1. So no embedded stylesheet, as I pointed out in my answer, right?

Comment: Yes :) . Only used <sub>...</sub> tag

Comment: This is awesome, it works. But kills any other formatting, so keep that in mind. E.g. links won't work, no paragraph breaks, etc.

Comment: Used <sbb>...<sub> within a Python Jupyter notebook, it made the tet smaller and the links still worked.

Comment: What's `<sub>` usually used for? (Is this a hack?)

Comment: @Danijel `sub`script, the text that goes below the line (like the 2 in H2O). The "inverse" will be `sup`erscript (like the 2 in x*x = x^2)

Comment: @JuanCA OK, so it is sort of a hack.

Comment: @Danijel yes, in this case, we could say it's kind of a trick. Other HTML text-formatting tags, like `<b>`old or `<i>`talic can be implemented easier by using markdown.

Answer (score 3):

Just because I don't see this mentioned here I'd like to add one interesting possibility. I know that GitHub's markdown is easy, but if you get at this point where you are sort of battling with it's limitations to get the styling just the way you like it, you might consider switching over to [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-pages/).

From that link:

> GitHub Pages are public webpages hosted and published through our site.
>
> You can create and publish GitHub Pages online using the Automatic Page Generator.

GitHub has special handling for a branch in your repo called `gh_pages`. Any content pushed to that branch will be published to a subdomain on github.io. Once done, your very own static website will appear at `https://your-username.github.io/your-project`.

Github makes it super easy to convert your existing markdown to some nice looking website (check out the Automatic Page Creator section in the repo settings) which you can then just pull in from the `gh_pages` branch and edit to your heart's content.

Answer (score 2):

While the CSS usedby GitHub is described in this [official guide](https://github.com/styleguide/css), I didn't find any example where you could embed your own stylesheet in a page served by GitHub.

And  section would be ignored.
That was [already the case two years ago for Gist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566979/6309) (for instance).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I achieved this by using <sub>...</sub> tag.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
<font size="+1">Description</font>
```

Comment: Can you show a working example? This didn't work for me.