# SyntaxHighlighter doesn't work on Blogger Dynamic Views?

Tags: blogger, blogspot, syntaxhighlighter, blogger-dynamic-views

Currently I plan to add [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to my Blogger (Dynamic Views). However, I tried all the methods on the Internet but still not be able to work it out, including [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335463/how-to-setup-syntax-highlighter-on-blogger) [[2]](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.hk/2013/01/adding-syntaxhighlighter-to-blogger.html) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464924/blogger-syntaxhighlighter-doesnt-work-at-all) [[4]](http://senthilkl.blogspot.hk/2012/11/syntax-highlighter-using-blogger.html) [[5]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29175/blogger-code-highlighting-in-dynamic-views) [[6]](http://blog.cruxframework.org/2011/10/easy-code-syntax-highlight-on-blogger.html).

Any idea on how to fix this? Or any alternative syntax highlighter suggested for Blogger Dynamic Views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure you include this code to your head :

```
<link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPerl.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script language='javascript'>
SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = 'http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf';
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

Now whenever you add codes to your blog post(add them inside pre tags) add this javascript at the end of every post(you can add it by switching to HTML tab in blogger post editor)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
</script>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just find a alternative way to do this (though not fixing the problem directly):

1. Use **Windows Live Writer** as the Blogger offline editor.
2. Download and install plug-in **[Paste As Visual Studio Code](http://plugins.live.com/writer/detail/paste-as-visual-studio-code)** for Windows Live Writer. And use it to insert code.

Although it can only insert code from `Visual Studio`, it seems enough for me. An example from [my blog](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/07/using-msxml-to-readwrite-xml-files.html) is as follows:

[image]