# social content locker for blogger.com blogs? is it possible

Tags: wordpress, blogger, facebook-social-plugins

How can I integrate social content locker in blogger blogs? We see in numbers of WordPress blogs and websites,
But in blooger.com blogs you see no plugin option

does anybody has another way or something like this?
I Want visitor to like, tweet or g+ before reading my posts.

thanks

Comment: It is possible with jQuery and some web programming knowledge like css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this working script for this what you need to do is first backup you template.
then edit HTML >search `<head>` tag and put this code after `<head>`

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

After that search `</head>` tag and put below code before this tag

```
<link href='https://sites.google.com/site/menightfury/home/social-locker/public/sociallocker_v1.6.0.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://sites.google.com/site/menightfury/home/social-locker/public/sociallockermin_v1.6.0.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#default-usage .to-lock').sociallocker({

    buttons: {order:["facebook-like","twitter-tweet","google-plus"]},

    twitter: {url:"https://www.facebook.com/www.mostsharedposts"},
    facebook: {url:"https://www.facebook.com/www.mostsharedposts"},
    google: {url:"https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/110589424466302901501/110589424466302901501"},

    text: {
      header: "Like us To Unlock This Content",
      message: "This content is locked. Like us on Twitter, Facebook or Google plus to unlock it."
    },

    locker: {close: false, timer: 0,},
    theme: "secrets"
  });
});
  //]]>
</script>
```

this is how to hide your code in post editor
go to post edit HTML and add this code

```
<article id="default-usage">
<div class="to-lock" style="display:none;">
Hello i am the hidden content
</div>
</article>
```

I implemented this in my blog [check demo](http://bit.ly/social-content-locker-for-blogger)

Comment: Thanks nabeel.
Finally we can do this with blogger blogs wow.

Comment: Man you made my day!  
It worked but in second post it's not showing any solution for this? Otherwise thnx :)

Comment: how to use dynamic post url for Facebook share?