# How to render brackets properly in bash code for a blogger post using SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: bash, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335463/how-to-setup-syntax-highlighter-on-blogger) and setup SyntaxHighlighter for my blogger. In addition, I added to the head

```
http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushBash.js
```

for rendering bash code, and then I tried to render a line like this

```
<pre name="code" class="bash">
    ls > output.txt
</pre>
```

But the `>` becomes `&gt;`, and I have tried the following, as well: `<`, `>`, `<>`, `><`, `<1>`, `<1a>`, `<a1a>`, `<a a>`, but none of them works, and all brackets get rendered to either `&gt;` or `&lt;`. I have even tried [`&#62;`](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119), but it becomes `&gt;`, too.

Surprisingly, `<a>` gets rendered to `<a>` correctly, so to me, seems that the brackets have to come in pair and there have to be some letters, but no space or numbers in between, why is that? How could I simply render the above line of code properly?

I found this problem when comparing these two posts:

1. [post 1](http://zyxue2012-technical.blogspot.ca/2012/11/starting-new-django-project.html): search for `pip freeze &gt; requirements.txt`. The corresponding html is `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
2. [post 2](http://zyxue2012-technical.blogspot.ca/2012/12/my-emacs-tip.html): search for `F3 F3 <space> C+n C+a F4`. The corresponding html is also just `F3 F3 <space> C+n C+a F4`.

Answer (score -1):

The head should look something like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shBrushBash.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Whatever_Theme_you_r_using.css">
<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all();</script>
</head>
```

All you have to do is to change all the "<" symbols to "`&lt;`"

Comment: No, it doesn't work. `&lt;` gets rendered to `&lt;`, so does `<`